# try to git commit but error in node_modules, which is gitignored

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, node-modules, commit

I'm trying to commit a vue.js project on a git repository. I'm sure my .gitignore works, because I already did a checkout without get the node_modules repository.
However when I commit, I have synthax errors appearing for my node_modules.

I tried to remove the node_modules repository, but I had a cannot find module error.
I tried to correct the error, but the computer find another error.

An example of the error I got :

> [user@server mgtsm]$ git commit -m "Ajout des templates de message"
> /home/user/git/mgtsm/node_modules/yorkie/node_modules/execa/index.js:2
> const childProcess = require('child_process'); ^^^^^ SyntaxError: Use
> of const in strict mode.
> at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
> at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
> at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
> at require (module.js:384:17)
> at Object. (/home/fs623/git/mgtsm/node_modules/yorkie/src/runner.js:3:15)
> at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>
> pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Has the `node_modules` folder already been committed?

Comment: The last line provides the clue: `pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)`

Comment: Check the linter configuration. If should be ignoring the `node_modules` folder

Comment: The node_modules has not been already committed.
What is the linter configuration @evolutionxbox ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sumurai8 I didn't saw it.  However I'm afraid to use it and break my git repository.

Comment: This isn't going to break the git repo. You have a "linter" checking the code on commit. It is complaining about `node_modules`. Which "linter" are you using?

Comment: Either you need to skip the hook (which kinda defeats its purpose), or you need to figure out how to configure yorkie/what node version they normally use. I am not familiar with yorkie, so I don't know what you need to change there. I am assuming you are using a newer or older version of node that does not allow certain syntax.